# configure plumbr for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Where should we add additional JVM args for elasticsearch? I need to configure plumbr tool for Elasticsearch instances.
I need to add this entry:

```
-javaagent:/my_location/plumbr.jar
```

I tried adding in plugin file under config. But the plumbr is not configured.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you run ES on *nix, there's /etc/default/elasticsearch file which has

```
# Additional Java OPTS
ES_JAVA_OPTS
```

You need to add java agent there:

```
ES_JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:/path/to/plumbr/plumbr.jar
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you @sserzant.  I am using ubuntu, and i updated JAVA_OPTS value in bin/elasticsearch.in.sh under elasticsearch directory